# Click "show more" button until all data in table is shown and fetch all data from table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to fetch all data from the table on this page
https://www.nets.eu/dk-da/l%C3%B8sninger/Registreringsnumre

But I need to click the "show more" button until all data is shown..

But no matter how many time I click the "show more" button the table keeps having 30 rows..!?

```
import sys
import time
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import json

class Scrape:
    display = None
    driver = None

    def __init__(self):
        #   Start display
        self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        self.display.start()

        #   Init driver
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5)

        self.load_page()

        time.sleep(5)

        self.close()

    def load_page(self):
        data = []
        url = 'https://www.nets.eu/dk-da/l%C3%B8sninger/Registreringsnumre'
        xpath = '//table[@class="itera-DataTable"]/tbody/tr'
        self.driver.get(url)

        try:
            table = self.driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CLASS_NAME, 'itera-DataTable')))

            print 'Table found!'

            i = 1
            while True:
                button = self.driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.CLASS_NAME, 'itera-nextbatchbox')))

                print 'Button %d found!' % (i)

                row_count = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath))
                print row_count

                button.click()

                i += 1

                if i > 5:
                    break

            i = 1
            for tr in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
                print 'TR %d' % (i)
                tr_data = []
                tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                if tds:
                    tr_data.append([td.text for td in tds])
                    data.append(tr_data)

                i += 1

            #print json.dumps(data)

        except TimeoutException:
            self.error('Table not found')

    def error(self, str):
        self.close()

        print>>sys.stderr, str
        sys.exit(1)

    def close(self):
        if self.driver is not None:
            self.driver.quit()
        self.display.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Scrape()
```

Comment: So how much data is in the db? How many pages of data are you expecting? You do have access to the db data, because you have permission to scrape this website, correct?

Comment: The click event function of see ore link defined in Itera.RegNumbers.js,  I think the possible reason of your issue come  from  two aspects.  1.  you not wait the page load before to click the see more link, browser is busy on rendering page, can't response the click event.  2. when you click the see more link the Itera.RegNumbers.js had not finish loading.  A quick way to detect is to add sleep 15s  after self.driver.get(url);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the root cause is about clicking on the button doesn't work. Use JavaScriptExecutor to click the button will solve this. See my code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
data = []
url = 'https://www.nets.eu/dk-da/l%C3%B8sninger/Registreringsnumre'
xpath = '//table[@class="itera-DataTable"]/tbody/tr'
driver.get(url)

try:
    table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'itera-DataTable')))
    print('Table found!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Table not found')


row_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath))
print(row_count)
while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.itera-nextbatchbox')))
        print('Button found!')
    except TimeoutException:
        break

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath( xpath)) > row_count)
        time.sleep(1)
        row_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath( xpath))
        print(row_count)
    except TimeoutException:
        print('No more rows. Rows count: ' + str(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath( xpath))))
```